# How to use private API `SLPSPostEventRecordTo` on macOS app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to use private API `SLPSPostEventRecordTo` on developing macOS app.

But the building app don't work.

## My code

### AppDeleagete.h

```
extern CGError SLPSPostEventRecordTo(ProcessSerialNumber *psn, uint8_t *bytes);
```

### AppDeleagate.m

```
SLPSPostEventRecordTo(&process, 0);
```

## Building error message

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SLPSPostEventRecordTo", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate activateWindow:] in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Undefined symbol: _SLPSPostEventRecordTo
```

I referenced these codes.

- https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai/blob/master/src/window_manager.c#L808
- https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai/blob/master/src/window_manager.h#L17

How can I use the `SLPSPostEventRecordTo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SL`* symbols are defined in `SkyLight.framework` located in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks`. In your Xcode project you can manually add `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks` to either `SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` or `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` and `-framework SkyLight` to `OTHER_LDFLAGS`.

Comment: I succeeded the building! The answer was corrent. Thanks you!